# Ninject passing in constructor values

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ninject

With Ninject, how do you configure the kernel so I can define what constructor values are passing into the instantiation of an object?

I have the following configured in a module:

```
Bind<IService1>()
    .To<Service1Impl>()
    .InSingletonScope()
    .Named("LIVE");
Bind<IService2>()
    .To<Service2Impl>()
    .InSingletonScope()
    .Named("LIVE")
    .WithConstructorArgument(
        "service1", 
        Kernel.Get<IService1>("LIVE"));
```

Service2Impl takes a constructor parameter of IService1 but I want this to come from the container. I also want to have named bindings as my code will be targeting different versions at runtime.

This seems to work but is it the right way to achieve what I want to do?
Should I be achieving without the use of named bindings and wiring different configuration modules into the kernel?

**EDIT**

I have used the ToMethod() method now to specify a delegate to call on request of a specific type. This seems a bit nicer as I'll get compile time warnings if the constructor configuration is wrong rather than having to know the name of the parameter I am passing first.

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I used ToMethod in the end, which allowed me to construct the required instance with constructors in order to maintain compile time errors.

For example:

```
.ToMethod(Func<IContext, T> method)

Bind<IWeapon>().ToMethod(context => new Sword());
```

Comment: Much prefer this syntax to .WithConstructorArgument, compiler catches refactoring errors. +1

Comment: Did you seriously have an application calling for a Weapon interface and Sword object?

Answer (score 18):

I would recommend the `WithConstructorParameter` overload that takes a lambda like so:

```
Bind<IService2>()
    .To<Service2Impl>()
    .InSingletonScope()
    .Named("LIVE")
    .WithConstructorArgument(
        "service1", 
        ctx => ctx.Kernel.Get<IService1>("LIVE"));
```

This will ensure that that the resolution of `IServive1` happens at the time of activation of `Service2Impl` and not at startup when the container is created. Whilst in your case it doesn't really matter as `Service1Impl` is singleton, there could be side effects on doing it in the way you originally wrote it:

- The binding for dependency that is injected by `WithConstructorArgument` has to already exist. This implies that all bindings have to done in a particular order. This creates can get tricky when there are multiple modules involved.
- Scoping issues can arise when custom scope is used. Ninject 2.0 introduced cache and collect scope management, binding to a constant is very likely to throw that into disarray.

Answer (score 6):

It seems you're looking at this the wrong way. Ninject will inject service 1 automatically into service 2 if it has it as constructor argument. There is not need for WithConstructorArgument in this case.

If there are multiple IService1 you should go for conditions. E.g. WhenParentNamed(...)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Providers can help you. Bind IService2 To a Provider. and in the Create method of Provider, use Kernel.Get("LIVE") to create the Service2Impl instance.

see the following link to know how to use Provider
https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Providers%2C-Factory-Methods-and-the-Activation-Context

Comment: Thanks, I saw that. Thought it was a bit too much code and as it says in the link you shared the ToMethod is a leaner version of a provider.

Answer (score 0):

I think `ToConstant()` is cleaner, the `InSingletonScope` is implicit:

```
Bind<IService2>().ToConstant(new Service2Impl(argument)))
                 .Named("LIVE");
```