# .NET memory profiling / risks for leaks / Ninject / Direct delegate roots

Tags: .net, asp.net, debugging, memory, ninject

I am profiling an application that uses Ninject for DI. Over the course of time, I am seeing lots of instances of the BindingBuilder class, which is used to define the objects defined in the container.

Ninject's "ToMethod" binding is used to define all the objects in the container. The context available in the lamba to access the kernel is then used to retrieve other objects from the container. Example:

```
Bind<IService>()
    .ToMethod(ctx => new CustomService(
        ctx.Kernel.GetDefault<IOtherService>(), 
        ctx.Kernel.GetDefault<IAnotherService>()
    ))
    .InSingletonScope();
```

Is it normal behaviour to see BindingBuilders increasing over time or should these references exist only once?

Answer (score 2):

ToMethod creates a new anonymous class within the `BindingBuilder` for the lambda expression. What you see is not an instance of `BindingBuilder` but something like `BindingBuilder<T>+c__DisplayClass1<IService>`

Furthermore you aren't using Ninject as intended. The binding above can be written much easier. Let Ninject decide what to inject instead of adding an explizit definition.

```
Bind<IService>().To<CustomService>.InSingletonScope();
```

Comment: thanks for this. The reason we have it like it is is that we have named instances that we specifically want to inject so we may define two implementations, with different names, for a given interface. How would we let Ninject decide the one to use in this scenario?

Comment: That's an entire different story and depends on the reason for having multiple implementations.
The answer to this question is no there is no memory leak for BindingBuilder.

Comment: That's fine, and I presumed there wouldn't be. Would you expect to see a gradual build up of anonymous classes via the BindingBuilder route? Do you have any guidance for named instances and the best way to inject those. I thought we were using the recommended approach but their might be a better way to do it?

Comment: I expect a single instance of a new anonymous class for each binding that uses ToMethod (or anyother method taking a lambda as argument).

Comment: Regarding the other question I succest asking a new question that includes information why you have multiple instances and what you want to achieve. e.g. Are these different strategies selected by some condition in the consumer of the strategy or is because you want to deploy it differently, .... As I said there is not one solution there are many for different situations. Currently it's just guessing.

Comment: Thanks Remo - I did post something about this a while ago, which I see you responded to (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065464/ninject-passing-in-constructor-values). Is there an example post of the WhenParentNamed stuff? Also, do we need the OnePerRequestModule configured? And to use the Ninject.Web.Common assembly?

Comment: @RemoGloor let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1261/discussion-between-tim-peel-and-remo-gloor)