# Ninject multiple binding of injected interface

Tags: c#, .net, ninject

I have the following classes:

```
using System;

interface IA { }

class A1 : IA { }

class A2 : IA { }

class B
{
    public B(IA a) {}
}

class BProvider : Provider<B>
{
    IA _a;

    public BProvider(IA a) { _a=a; }

    protected override B CreateInstance(IContext context) { return new B(_a); }
}
```

ninject module Load() code:

```
Bind<IA>().To<A1>();
Bind<IA>().To<A2>();
Bind<B>().ToProvider<BProvider>();
```

main code:

```
kernel.GetAll<IA>(); // works fine
kernel.GetAll<B>(); // I expect to get IEnumerable<B> with two elements, but instead of this I get an error that there are multiple bindings of IA and ninject cannot determine which to use
```

So the question is if I can make the last statement work as expected or do it some other way?

Answer (score 2):

It will throw that exception because Ninject will need to create an instance of object of type `BProvider`. To do it, it has to fill in the dependency on `IA`. But moment... there are two bindings on `IA`, which one should I choose?....

You can use some conditional binding to decide which implementation should be used.
One way is with `NamedAttribute`:

```
Bind<IA>().To<A1>();
Bind<IA>().To<A2>().Named("SecondImpl");
Bind<B>().ToProvider<BProvider>();


class BProvider : Provider<B>
{
    IA _a;

    public BProvider([Named("SecondImpl")]IA a) { _a=a; }

    protected override B CreateInstance(IContext context) { return new B(_a); }
}
```

In this case A1 will be injected as default where `NamedAttribute` is not specified.

or like @Remo Gloor explains in this post: [Configuring Ninject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627894/configuring-ninject)

```
Bind<IA>().To<A1>();
Bind<IA>().To<A2>().WhenParentNamed("NeedSecondImpl");
Bind<B>().ToProvider<BProvider>().Named("NeedSecondImpl");
```

This is bit cleaner, because you dont have to tie your code to Ninject and can just let it on configuration (in one place).